# How knowing queryid get query string in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, query

I try use postgres_exporter.

It monitors postgres and sends metrics to prometheus.

It has a request
https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter/blob/master/queries.yaml#L137

The output will be a queryid table and its metrics.

How knowing queryid get query string in Postgresql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is managed by pg_stat_statements extension in the view that has the same name.
To link queryid and query you need to query the view pg_stat_statements:

```
postgres=# \d pg_stat_statements;
                    View "public.pg_stat_statements"
       Column        |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 userid              | oid              |           |          | 
 dbid                | oid              |           |          | 
 queryid             | bigint           |           |          | 
 query               | text             |           |          | 
 calls               | bigint           |           |          | 
 total_time          | double precision |           |          | 
 min_time            | double precision |           |          | 
 max_time            | double precision |           |          | 
 mean_time           | double precision |           |          | 
 stddev_time         | double precision |           |          | 
 rows                | bigint           |           |          | 
 shared_blks_hit     | bigint           |           |          | 
 shared_blks_read    | bigint           |           |          | 
 shared_blks_dirtied | bigint           |           |          | 
 shared_blks_written | bigint           |           |          | 
 local_blks_hit      | bigint           |           |          | 
 local_blks_read     | bigint           |           |          | 
 local_blks_dirtied  | bigint           |           |          | 
 local_blks_written  | bigint           |           |          | 
 temp_blks_read      | bigint           |           |          | 
 temp_blks_written   | bigint           |           |          | 
 blk_read_time       | double precision |           |          | 
 blk_write_time      | double precision |           |          | 

postgres=#
```

For example:

```
select queryid, query from pg_stat_statements;
```

Comment: Thanks!  ```SELECT queryid, query from pg_stat_statements where queryid = 1562243590;```